# Javascript em resize based on window/viewport dimension not affecting in-doc style text/css?

Tags: javascript, html, css, media-queries, fluid-layout

I'm using the following to resize text (and other elements) based on browser size.

```
(function(w){
   var run = w.onresize = function(){
    document.body.style.fontSize=window.innerWidth*.009536+"px"
   }
   run();
})(window);
```

However, it's not affecting anything within the following:

```
<style type="text/css">
.search-sprite
{
background-image: url(../../images/searchsprite.png);
height: 2.46em;
cursor: pointer;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

.search-sprite:hover {
background-position: 0px -2.46em;   
}
</style>
```

Why?  How can I fix it?

Comment: Hey it can be done using css..so u wanna try it or be with javascript only?

Comment: I am ok with CSS... does it use media queries?  If so, I often find that due to the breadth and number of them required the adjustments are too large to be truly effective.

Comment: is it ok with media queries or use % in font?

Comment: Not totally sure what you mean.  Are you saying a solution is to change em to %?

Comment: look below my code and apply to your css...

Answer (score 0):

```
@media screen and (max-device-width : 320px)
{
  body or yourdiv element
  {
    font:size(px/em/cm);
  }
}
@media screen and (max-device-width : 1024px)
{
  body or yourdiv element
  {
    font:size(px/em/cm);
  }
}
```

You can give it manually according to screen size of screen.Just have a look of different screen size and add manually the font size.